# Construtor PHP não identifica valor da variável

Tags: php, construtor

Alguém poderia me dizer porque no "parent::__construct('$conta');", se eu colocar uma variável ali ele n a identifica? Já tentei de todo jeito, só funciona se eu digitar direto o nome da tabela, esse $conta vem do identifica, já coloquei echo $conta antes do "parent::__construct('$conta');"

```
<?php 
require_once('usuarios.v.php');
include 'identifica.php';

class User extends Usuarios{
public function __construct(){
echo $conta;
parent::__construct('$conta');
}
}
```

e ele pega o nome da tabela normal, porém, quando o coloco ali dentro ele n identifica. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<?php 
require_once('usuarios.v.php');
include 'identifica.php';

class User extends Usuarios{
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct('$conta');
}
}
```

Comment: Tira a aspas simples porque vai entender como uma String, testa ai e me fala.

Comment: Já tentei assim, com duplas, simples, sem e msm assim n funciona

Comment: Se eu der um echo $conta; antes da linha do parent, ele imprime normal, mas se for uma linha dps ele tb n identifica.

Comment: Coloque a classe usuario

Comment: RESOLVIDO - fiz isso<?php 
require_once('usuarios.v.php');

class User extends Usuarios{
   public function __construct($conta){
include 'identifica.php';
    parent::__construct($conta);
}
}

Comment: Coloquei o include dentro da function e passei a variável pelo construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO ->

```
<?php 
require_once('usuarios.v.php');

class User extends Usuarios{
 public function __construct($conta){
include 'identifica.php';
parent::__construct($conta);
}
}
```